# Case insensitive Full Name dictionary search

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary with "Full Name": "Birthday" for numerous people as an exercise.
The program should ask
"Who's birthday do you want to look up?"
I will input a name, say "Benjamin Franklin"
And it will return his birthday: 1706/01/17.

Alright, the problem I am encountering is name capitalization.
How can I input "benjamin franklin" and still find "Benjamin Franklin" in my dictionary? I am familiar with .lower() and .upper() functions, however I am not able to implement them correctly, is that the right way to approach this problem?

Here is what I have

```python
bday_dict = {"Person1": "YYYY/MM/DD1",
         "Person2": "YYYY/MM/DD2",
         "Benjamin Franklin": "1706/01/17"}


def get_name(dict_name):

    name = input("Who's birthday do you want to look up? > ")
    return name


def find_bday(name):

    print(bday_dict[name])


find_bday(get_name(bday_dict))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to do this is to keep the keys in your dictionary lowercase. If you can't do that for whatever reason, have a dictionary from lowercase to the real key, and then keep the original dictionary.

Otherwise, Kraigolas's solution works well, but it is O(N) whereas hashmaps are supposed to be constant-time, and thus for really large dictionaries the other answer will not scale.

So, when you are setting your keys, do `bday_dict[name.lower()] = value` and then you can query by `bday_dict[input.lower()]`.

Alternatively:

```py
bday_dict = {"John": 1}
name_dict = {"john": "John"}

def access(x):
    return bday_dict[name_dict[x.lower()]]
```

Comment: One can also pre-generate the second dict using something like `name_dict = {s.lower() : s for s in bday_dict}`.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Wow, Yeah I didn't want to minimise the names. Kraigolas' method would work in my case, but I guess yours would be more proper programming practice, thank you

Comment: @Mounir Depending on what you do, it might be better practice to make the key an ID and the value a dict of fields like name, birthday, height, etc, or to use an actual database. but to avoid linear-time access this is a simple option for simpler projects.

Comment: @Mounir To add to this, you could just use one dictionary, where the value stored is a tuple of `(name, birthday)`, with a key of lowercase name ie. `name.lower()  : (name, bday)` if you need to retain proper name capitalization. You can even go beyond this and remove punctuation from names for your key, while retaining the actual name in this tuple. This would be appropriate if most or all of the time, you want to get both the name and birthday together (for example, if you wanted to write "Benjamin Franklin's birthday is 1706/01/17")

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Oh and iterate through the ID and pull out the information of interest, that would save me the hassle of trouble-shooting the input given. I like that very much, I'm going to add a few characteristics to every name and do that for practice.

Comment: @Kraigolas Ooh ok, that's a good idea as well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most straight forward way I can think of to solve this is the following:

```
def get_birthday(name):
    global bday_dict
    for person, bday in bday_dict.items():
        if name.lower() == person.lower():
            return bday
    return "This person is not in bday_dict"
```

Here, you just iterate through the entire dictionary using the person's name paired with their birthday, and if we don't find them, just return a message saying we don't have their birthday.

If you know that all names will capitalize the first letter of each word, you can just use:

```
name = ' '.join([word.capitalize() for word in name.split()])
```

then you can just search for that. This is not always the case. For example, for "Leonardo da Vinci" this will not work, so the original answer is probably the most reliable way to do this.

One final way to do this would be to just store the names as lowercase from the beginning in your dictionary, but this might not be practical when you want to draw a name from the dictionary as well.

Comment: @NikolaBenes That's fair, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mounir I've added an update to the answer if you can safely assume that every name in your dictionary can capitalize the first letter of each word in it (ie. benjamin franklin becomes Benjamin Franklin).

Comment: @Kraigolas Ah that's smart, I like how you thought of Leonardo da Vinci, I was planning on having the 4 Innovators written about by Walter Isaacson in my dictionary, so you saved me future trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what your exercise allows, I would put the names in the dictionary as all lowercase or uppercase. So:

```
bday_dict = {"person1": "YYYY/MM/DD1",
     "person2": "YYYY/MM/DD2",
     "benjamin franklin": "1706/01/17"}
```

And then look up the entered name in the dictionary like this:

```
def find_bday(name):
    print(bday_dict[name.lower()])
```

You may also want to do a check that the name is in the dictionary beforehand to avoid an error:

```
def find_bday(name):
    bday = bday_dict.get(name.lower(), None)
    if bday:
        print(bday)
    else:
        print("No result for {}.".format(name))
```

Comment: The exercise doesn't specify but I didn't want to minimise the names myself, I thought it would be improper.